# Access element through local dom in unit test

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x

Consider following code:

```
<test-fixture id="fixture-one">
    <template>
        <display-enter-button id="testEl"></display-enter-button>
    </template>
</test-fixture>

<script>
    suite('Query Selector Tests', function() {
        test('On click function called', function() {
            var circle = fixture('fixture-one').shadowRoot.querySelector('.btn');
            var proto = Document.getElementById('testEl').constructor.prototype;
            var func = sinon.spy(proto, '_btnClick');
            circle.click();
            sinon.assert.called(func);
    });
});
</script>
```

Is there a way to rewrite so I can access the proto element via Polymer local DOM (this.$..).

Instead of

```
var proto = Document.getElementById('testEl').constructor.prototype;
```

I look for something like:

```
var proto = this.$.testEl.constructor.prototype;
```

(My example doesn't work..)

Comment: if you log `this` in your console, you will see the reason why it wouldn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a test, you need to hold onto the fixture object with a variable name.  You can then use it as your web component.

```
var el = fixture('fixture-one');
var circle = el.shadowRoot.querySelector('.btn');
var proto = el.constructor.prototype;
```

Check its id; el.id should equal 'testEl'.

Remember that 'this' is used in context and you can't use it outside of the element itself.  In a test, rather than `this.$`, you should use `el.$`.  Also, keep in mind that the test fixture itself isn't returned when you call `fixture()`; the element inside the template is returned.

Comment: Perfect! This answer made me understand the code a lot better too, which is great as this was a first unit test. I will reuse this code a lot, thx for helping me having it right.

Answer (score 0):

With `var proto = fixture('fixture-one');` proto will be display-enter-button.

Comment: i hope this is your intention.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I meant. The code I have is already working, but I want to know if I can rewrite var proto = Document.getElementById('testEl').constructor.prototype; so that instead of Doucment.getElementById(//...) I use this.$